# UI Bug when viewing the Achievements dropdown

Tags: support, bug

When I'm on my profile page and I view the Achievements drop down menu, I get a strange artifact in the overlay(?).

[image: NUTS]

It appears to be the progress bar tracking my points to the next site privilege.

[image: NUTS]

The most beloved and cherished @jcolebrand asked me to post the issue here.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a name people have for me around these parts, and cherished and beloved aint it.

Comment: @jcolebrand someday they'll get over their monkeyphobia.

Comment: FYI - This has also been reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301447/next-privilege-overlapping-achievements).

Comment: @bluefeet if you want to close this as a duplicate that's fine

Comment: Can't close as dup cross site, just pointing you to it if you want to maybe see how that one get resolved. :)

Comment: @bluefeet ah, okay -- thanks!